# how to install gtk3 on void linux

Tags: linux, gtk, i3-window-manager

i am using i3 on void linux and i am having this issue when installing gtk3 when running the following command:

```
 sudo xbps-install -S gtk+3-devel
```

it returns this error:

```
Password:
[*] Updating `https://alpha.de.repo.voidlinux.org/current/x86_64-repodata' ...
libuuid-2.33.1_2 (update) breaks installed pkg `libfdisk-2.33_1'
libuuid-2.33.1_2 (update) breaks installed pkg `util-linux-2.33_1'
libblkid-2.33.1_2 (update) breaks installed pkg `libfdisk-2.33_1'
libblkid-2.33.1_2 (update) breaks installed pkg `util-linux-2.33_1'
libmount-2.33.1_2 (update) breaks installed pkg `util-linux-2.33_1'
Transaction aborted due to unresolved dependencies.
```

i tried installing the listed packages but still no success 
anyway i can install it?
i tried running

```
sudo xbps-install -S gtk+3
```

and it told me it was installed but there's no ui to edit gtk themes

Answer (score 1):

Try

sudo xbps-install -Suv

followed by the installation you want to make. Note the all important 'v'.

This has always resolved the "Transaction aborted due to unresolved dependencies" problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, updating your system via

```
sudo xbps-install -Su
```

takes care of this.

Comment: Is this meant as a comment rather than an answer? It is a question so I would think so